# Conditional Validator Angular - Check other form control values and validate with regex pattern

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been working on a conditional validator that essentially needs to validate values on 3 different fields.

If none of the fields have a value the form is invalidated.

If one of the fields has a value the form is valid.

Each field also has a regex pattern it needs to be validated agaisn't whenever a value is entered.

I have tried using a conditional validator...

```
 conditionalValidator(predicate: () => boolean, validator: ValidatorFn): ValidatorFn {
    return ((formControl: AbstractControl) => {
      if (!formControl.parent) {
        return null;
      }
      if (predicate()) {
        return validator(formControl);
      }
      return null;
    })
  }
```

But my problem is, this is still making all 3 fields required even if another one has a value, I need to consider this in the conditionalvalidator just not sure how to do this.

These are the form controls I'm validating with...

```
      'DaytimeNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.conditionalValidator(() => !this.CustomerForm.get('MobileNumber')!.value && !this.CustomerForm.get('EveningNumber')!.value, Validators.pattern(this.landlineRegex))]),
      'MobileNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.conditionalValidator(() => !this.CustomerForm.get('DaytimeNumber')!.value && !this.CustomerForm.get('EveningNumber')!.value, Validators.pattern(this.mobileRegex))]),
      'EveningNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.conditionalValidator(() => !this.CustomerForm.get('DaytimeNumber')!.value && !this.CustomerForm.get('MobileNumber')!.value, Validators.pattern(this.landlineRegex))]),
```

Any suggestions on the best approach for this or some useful resources I can refer to would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to apply two separate validations: the first is a regex validator that should be applied to each individual control, the other is a group-level validator that checks if one of the controls has a value.
Separating these two should help simplify the problem (and the code).
The 'oneOfPhoneFields' validator could look something like this:

```
function validateOneOfPhoneFields(form: FormGroup) {
  const daytime = form.get('dayTimeNumber').value
  const mobile = form.get('mobileNumber').value
  const evening = form.get('eveningNumber').value

  return daytime || mobile || evening
    ? null
    : { oneOfPhoneFieldsRequired: true }
}
```

It can be applied to the entire form or a nested formGroup.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are looking for a way to perform [cross-validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms). Please check the link for more information, and also examples on how to validate fields based on the value of other fields in your form.

You can remove the required validator in your controls, as you want to control the `required` aspect in the cross-validator (only one should be required, not all). Leave only the `Validators.pattern` validator for your controls and add the cross validator at the form level.

```
'DaytimeNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(this.landlineRegex)]),
'MobileNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(this.mobileRegex)]),
'EveningNumber': new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(this.landlineRegex)]),
```

Then in your cross validator function you could have something like this:

```
export const multiPhoneNumberValidator: ValidatorFn = (
  control: AbstractControl
): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const dayNumber = control.get('DaytimeNumber');
  const mobileNumber = control.get('MobileNumber');
  const eveningNumber = control.get('EveningNumber');

  const hasValidDayNumber = dayNumber?.value && dayNumber.valid;
  const hasValidMobileNumber = mobileNumber?.value && mobileNumber.valid;
  const hasValidEveningNumber = eveningNumber?.value && eveningNumber.valid;

  return hasValidDayNumber || hasValidMobileNumber || hasValidEveningNumber
    ? null
    : { phoneNumberRequired: true };
};
```

You can then go ahead and apply the cross-validator to your form, (or the enclosing form group) like in the documentation. In the component, where you have the form group instantiated, it should look similar to this:

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  // the controls for the phone numbers
}, { validators: multiPhoneNumberValidator })
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But how would you extend this to also consider the pattern validation as well?

Comment: @orangejuice I updated the answer to better reflect my idea.

Comment: thank you Octavian, but where would you call this from in the component? as I would need to call it everytime the value for one of these fields changes no?

Comment: @orangejuice Going through the link in my answer should make it trivial to apply, please take a look.

Comment: @orangejuice, Octavian say you that  you has a validation in each FormControl, and another one of the formGroup: `this.form: this.formGroup=new FormGroup({ DaytimeNumber:new FormControl(null,Validators.pattern(..)..}, multiPhoneNumberValidator)`